# SAMBA unbale access from other linux based systems

Tags: windows, samba, sharing

I have an ubuntu server 20:

- Distributor ID:  Ubuntu
- Description: Ubuntu 20.04.2 LTS
- Release: 20.04
- Codename:    focal

I installed an ubuntu share in many ways before but neither worked from Linux based systems at all. :(. I have to have access to booth windows and Linux system of my share. But only I can access this under windows.
I had read and tried tons of forums and threads but neither worked.

My actual configuration is :

```
global]
   unix charset = UTF-8
   workgroup = WORKGROUP
   server string = %h server (Samba, Ubuntu)
   log file = /var/log/samba/log.%m
   log level = 1
   max log size = 1000
   logging = file
   panic action = /usr/share/samba/panic-action %d
   server role = standalone server
   obey pam restrictions = yes
   unix password sync = yes
   passwd program = /usr/bin/passwd %u
   passwd chat = *Enter\snew\s*\spassword:* %n\n *Retype\snew\s*\spassword:* %n\n *password\supdated\ssuccessfully* .
   pam password change = yes
   map to guest = bad user
   usershare allow guests = yes
   client min protocol = NT1


[publicshare]
   path = /sare
   writable = yes
   guest ok = yes
   guest only = yes
   force create mode = 775
   force directory mode = 775
```

My samba info:

```
mrkiss@microserver:~$ sudo smbstatus

Samba version 4.11.6-Ubuntu
PID     Username     Group        Machine                                   Protocol Version  Encryption           Signing              
----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
3350    nobody       nogroup      192.168.1.113 (ipv4:192.168.1.113:39558)  SMB2_02           -                    -                    

Service      pid     Machine       Connected at                     Encryption   Signing     
---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
share        3350    192.168.1.113 Sun Aug  1 11:20:39 AM 2021 UTC  -            -           

Locked files:
Pid          User(ID)   DenyMode   Access      R/W        Oplock           SharePath   Name   Time
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
3350         65534      DENY_NONE  0x81        RDONLY     NONE             /share   Movie/Movies/Single/DVD/Uj/W_The Bounty/VIDEO_TS   Sun Aug  1 11:22:55 2021
```

Comment: You start with Ubuntu Server 20 (which implies a *snap* only 20 build) then mention Ubuntu 20.04 (ie. a *deb* based system).  Ubuntu has had both *year* (snap only products) **and** *year.month* systems (*deb* package based) since 2016, so please correct & use only one product please  (they are similar yes, but different; with the 20.04 being more larger but more powerful than the smaller 20; 20 faster to spin up so great for devices/cloud etc)

Comment: I take it that 'path = /sare' is a typo. What Linux clients are you trying to connect from and how. I ask this because if you can connect from Windows machines, this means the server appears to be working.

Comment: Hi Rowland. Unfortunately that is a typo but that not working with the right name what is share currently.